# JavaScript -- Unity Getting percentage of a value

Tags: javascript, math, unity-game-engine, percentage

Hello fellow programmers.

Again I come here to ask for your help. In my game that I am making I added xp or points as I called it. Every time you get enough points, the points will go to zero and the points needed for level up will get multiplied by five and then divided by 1,5. So, I said: "It would be stupid to have a leveling system without a loading bar!". So I quickly made a loading bar and I needed to get the percentage. Only problem is that I don't know how. So I looked it up a bit on the internet and found this:

```
pointsPerc = ((Game.points * 100) * Game.maxPoints);
```

But that didn't work out so I Googled a bit more and found this:

```
pointsPerc = ((Game.maxPoints / Game.points) / 100);
```

So how do I actually do this ?

---

Historic explanatory note:

[image]

Javascript (aka "unityscript") has not been available in Unity for some years; Unity is c# only.

Comment: Please don't post that I need to write code in C#. I've been told that a lot.

Comment: describe in what way that "didn't work out"

Comment: NOTE @NikolaZagorac. Do NOT use "unityscript". ***It is deprecated*** and being removed from Unity. The good news is, it is actually far easier to use c#. Change to c# from today.

Comment: You should use [jQuery](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif). You can do literally anything with it!

Comment: If I only knew how. Does Unity even support jQuery? Joe I know but I don't have the time to learn C#. This is my last year in elementary school and I need to study for the final test. Don't know how it's called in English.

Answer (score 1):

You need to multiply by 100 not divide.

```
let floatPercentage = (5 / 10) * 100;
let percentage = Math.floor(floatPercentage);
```

The second line is to get a nice `Int`.

Comment: `parseInt` on a `Number` is hugely wasteful, as it will perform unneeded `String` coercion and parsing. Just `Math.floor` or `~~` it.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. The game would just return 0. The points were set to 40 and the maxPoints were set to 100.I don't know why it returns 0. 40 / 100 = 0.4 times 100 would be 40. idk why it does this :(

Answer (score 1):

As long as David's answer can help you, it doesn't refer directly to your sample. So:

```
pointsPerc = ((Game.points / Game.maxPoints) * 100);
```

is what you need.

`(Game.points / Game.maxPoints)` will give you value between 0..1 and then you just multiply it by 100 to get 0..100 value representing percentage